# problema al implementar HTML en Android studios

Tags: javascript, java, html, android-studio, webview

Eh creado una grafica a tiempo real con canvasjs en html y en el navegador todo me funciona bien, pero al querer implementarlo a android studios no me muestra dicha grafica

primero cree el acesso WebView en activity_main
despues agregue el siguiente codigo para hacer el llamado en MainActivity

```
package com.example.analizadormovil;

 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.webkit.WebView;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String myurl="file:///android_asset/index.html";
    WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.loadUrl(myurl);


  }
}
```

y despues pase mi codigo html, css y js en una carpeta assest

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>PASTRANA</title>
<link href="images/favicon-30x30.png" type="image/png" rel="icon" sizes="16x16">
<link href="images/favicon-32x32.png" type="image/png" rel="icon" sizes="32x32">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="digits.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="EN">

<div class="menu">
  <span class="" title="R_100">100</span>
  <span class="menu-active" title="R_10">10</span>
  <span class="" title="R_25">25</span>
  <span class="" title="R_50">50</span>
  <span class="" title="R_75">75</span>
  <span class="" title="RDBEAR">BEAR</span>
  <span class="" title="RDBULL">BULL</span>
</div>

<div id="digits" class="digits">
  <span class="_"  hidden="hidden"></span>
  <span class="_" hidden="hidden"></span>
  <span class="_" hidden="hidden"></span>
  <span class="_" hidden="hidden"></span>
  <span class="_" hidden="hidden"></span>
  <span class="_" hidden="hidden"></span>
  <span class="_" hidden="hidden"></span>
  <span class="_" hidden="hidden"></span>
  <span class="_" hidden="hidden"></span>
  <span class="_" hidden="hidden"></span>
  <span class="_" ></span>
  <span class="_" ></span>
  <span class="_" ></span>
  <span class="_" ></span>
  <span class="_" ></span>
  <span style="margin-left: 120px" id="num5" class="_"></span>
  <span id="num4" class="_"></span>
  <span id="num3" class="_"></span>
  <span id="num2" class="_"></span>
  <span id="num1" class="_"></span>
 </div>
 <div id="headcol" class="headcol">
  <span class="_"  hidden="hidden"></span>
  <span class="_" hidden="hidden"></span>
  <span class="_" hidden="hidden"></span>
  <span class="_" hidden="hidden"></span>
  <span class="_" hidden="hidden"></span>
  <span class="_" hidden="hidden"></span>
  <span class="_" hidden="hidden"></span>
  <span class="_" hidden="hidden"></span>
  <span class="_" hidden="hidden"></span>
  <span class="_" hidden="hidden"></span>
  <span class="_" ></span>
  <span class="_" ></span>
  <span class="_" ></span>
  <span class="_" ></span>
  <span class="_" ></span>
  <span style="margin-left: 120px" id="num6" class="_"></span>
  <span id="num7" class="_"></span>
  <span id="num8" class="_"></span>
  <span id="num9" class="_"></span>
  <span id="num10" class="_"></span>
 </div>

 <div class="chartContainer" id="chartContainer"></div>
 <div id="SpotArrow" class="SpotArrow">
  <span class="_" ></span>
  <span class="_" ></span>
  <span class="_" ></span>
  <span class="_" ></span> 
  <span class="_" ></span>
  <span class="_" ></span>
  <span class="_" ></span>
  <span class="_" ></span>
  <span class="_" ></span>
  <span class="_" ></span>
  <span class="_" ></span>
  <span class="_" ></span>
  <span class="_" ></span>
  <span class="_" ></span>
  <span class="_" ></span>
  <span class="_" ></span>
  <span class="_" ></span>
  <span class="_" ></span>
  <span class="_" ></span>
  <span class="_" ></span>
  <span class="_" ></span>
  <span class="_" ></span>
  <span class="_" ></span> 
  </div>
 <div class="chartContainerAxisCord" id="chartContainerAxisCord"></div>
 <div class="chartContainerDigitEven" id="chartContainerDigitEven"></div>
 <div class="chartContainerDigitOdd" id="chartContainerDigitOdd"></div>
 <div class="chartContainerDigit" id="chartContainerDigit"></div>

<div id="arrow_up" class="arrow_up">
  <span class="_"></span>
  </div>
 <div id="arrow_down" class="arrow_down">
  <span class="_"></span>
 </div>

<script src="canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

No me marca ningun error, me ejecuta la aplicacion pero no me muestra nada!

en el navegador si me funciona todo bien, Les agradeceria mucho si pudieran ayudarme.
Muchas Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

necesitarás permiso de lectura

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: la verdad yo tambien en android studios, podrias explicarme un poco de los permisos de lectura ?

Comment: man, muchas gracias tenias razon use los siguiente permisos y me funciono

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: @Tonof no puede funcionar completamente ya que no cargarìa los .js o imagenes porque necesitas paths absolutos.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que la pàgina usa paths relativos para cargar los recursos que son importantes como en este caso el .js, pero si usas paths relativos, la pàgina trata de buscar estos elementos dentro de la aplicaciòn

Cambia a paths absolutos!

por ejemplo:

```
<link href="https://www.dominio.com/.../images/favicon-30x30.png" type="image/png" rel="icon" sizes="16x16">

<link href="https://www.dominio.com/.../images/favicon-32x32.png" type="image/png" rel="icon" sizes="32x32">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.dominio.com/.../style.css">

<script src="https://www.dominio.com/.../canvasjs.min.js"></script>
```

obviamente debes definir el permiso de internet para cargar el contenido

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```